# If Timestamp is 0, then say? - PHP

Tags: php

So, I have a data table that shows user account expiry, thing is -- I'm using unix timestamp, and when there's no expiry, it shows an old date, like 31-12-1969, how do I in php, if expire equals 31-12-1969 when echoing the date, make it say 'None' instead of 31-12-1969? This is extremely basic, but forgive me.. I'm still learning :c

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y' ,$userInfo['expire']); ?>
```

Comment: Use an if else statement

Comment: Please consider searching for a similar question and show what you have tried.  This website does not exist as a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<?php echo !empty($userInfo['expire']) ? date('d-m-Y' ,$userInfo['expire']) : "None"; ?>
```

Written as full if statement (the above is just a short version of the one below)

```
if (!empty($userInfo['expire'])) {
    echo date('d-m-Y' ,$userInfo['expire'])
} else {
    echo "None";
}
```

**Some explaination for the 1969 date**

The 1969 date is shown when the unix timestamp (the `date()` input) is empty. The unix timestamp started at the start of the year 1970. So when the input is empty it defaults to that date.

Answer (score 1):

Desired results can be produced like this:

```
<?php
    if($userinfo['expire']) {
        echo date('d-m-Y', $userinfo['expire']);
    } else {
        echo "None";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try following

```
<?php
    if(is_integer($userinfo['expire']) && $userinfo['expire'] > 0) 
    {
        $expiry = strtotime($userinfo['expire']);
        echo date('d-m-Y', $expiry);
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "None";
    }
?>
```

Actually no need to try strtotime but it is best practice.

Comment: Can you explain why strtotime is best practice?

Comment: php date function's second argument is time stamp. If there might be space before or after time stamp, strtotime convert into pure unix timestamp. There is also case when we store date time in yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s format in databse table. At that time, date function will also work. If we change date time  format at database level in future, we have not require any change in php code.